# What's a good method for serving content in different languages using asp?

Tags: asp-classic, language-design

I'm trying to figure out which would be the best way to go about serving asp classic pages in different languages. Some of the content on the page is generated server-side and some is hard-coded html. I would like to create a drop-down to select between different languages so that the server-side generated html as well as the hard-coded page content changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some options:

- Place *all* localizable content into database and get them as you need:

  - `<%= GetLiteral("Disclaimer", Session("language")) %>`
- Load a `Scripting.Dictionary` in global.asa with all localizable content and place it within an Application variable ([beware](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194803))
- To create a folder for each language (and use SSI `#includes` for common stuff, like layout)

From this set, first option is your best shot.

If you're starting a new application, I suggest you to look for an alternative platform, like ASP.NET.

Comment: Great answers. I'm a .net programmer, but unfortunately I have to get my hands dirty with asp classic. The experience hasn't been pleasant :)